# Passing A Js File Objects Array To Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I wonder if someone can help me with this as I'm new to JavaScript.

I have a form, and within it I have a file input. However, when a file is uploaded I need to manipulate it and add new properties. So I extract the file from the input like so:

```
let uploadedFile = [];
for (let val of this.files) {
uploadedFile.push(val)
    }

for (val of uploadedFile){

//Check file extension to classify the file type:
let extension = val.name.split('.')
extension = String((extension[extension.length-1]).toLowerCase());
let fileType = val.type;

//Arrays to hold extensions types we want to identify
const imageExtensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png']
const documentExtensions = ['xls','xlsx','csv','pdf']

//Classify files and push to global files array
if (imageExtensions.includes(extension)){
let newFile = new File([val], `${crname}-nr-${FileCount}.${extension}`, {type: `${fileType}`});

newFile.originalName = `${val.name}`
globalFilesArray.push(newFile);
        }
}
```

So as you can see the new file objects are pushed to an array named 'globalFilesArray'

Now in Flask i'm typically accessing the form data using the request module.

Must I now pass the array into a separate hidden file input so I can access it when the entire form is submitted?

I'm a bit stumped with this because I need this to happen only when the form is submitted so I can also access the rest of the input fields in the form.